# Cannot view code in the object

Tags: vb6

I'm not sure if this is right, but I can't view the "code behind" in VB6. Everytime I click the "view code" for an object (for example a button), the code does not display.

Can you help me with this or any workaround for this? I need to do a breakpoint on this.

Comment: VB6 doesn't have "code behind". Can you give a better example of what you're trying to do? Are you trying to set a breakpoint on the button click event handler?

Comment: what I meant is that every time i click the "view code" button or even double click the control, the code does not show. I don't know what it's called that's why I used "code behind".

Comment: Double-clicking any control or even the form itself should display the .frm file with the code. If you don't have your windows in VS6 maximized, that might be worth trying in case the form has somehow been loaded out of your viewable area.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Could not view the code or the designer.

Seems that VB6 lost track of where things should be displayed, whether offscreen or not I could not tell. Kept clicking View Code and View Object, and neither worked.

Found the solution:

- Attempt to open the code or designer that doesn't show up. (It will get opened, just won't show)
- Select Window from the menu, then select Cascade.
- You should then see the code/designer show up on the screen. No re-install or remove/add needed.
- You may need to do this each time, even after saving the .vbp (project) file, upon re-opening VB6 the files once again are not showing for me, but Cascade makes them visible again. (Anyone have any ideas on how to make this more permanent?)

Enjoy!

Comment: Alternatively, close VB, and delete the `projectname.vbw` file

Comment: I had the same issue and turned out to be my monitor setup. I have 4 monitors, two on top and two on bottom. it only works on the bottom two and i have to keep hitting cascade on the top ones. weird but at least i have a work around.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove the form which is not showing the code in the project explorer window and add it again by right clicking on the project explorer window then select Add -> Form -> (instead of selecting in "New" tab navigate on the "Existing" tab then choose the form you have just remove and try viewing its code again). It will work 100% :D

Answer (score 0):

Double click your controls and the source code will be shown.

Go to this link. 
[vb6 tutor](http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson2.html)

Comment: been doing that for many times but the code does not show up. :(

Comment: Go to the link i provided. And if it is not working still.. i think you need to re install it.

Comment: actually, i found out that it's just one form. the rest are the same. Also I would like to ask too that this form has a lighter shade in the icon. Does this mean that this is hidden?

Comment: I Think the best way is to Try to create new form..and delete the first one which having you a trouble. and go to this site for tutorial. http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/vbtutor.html